# Как составить запрос MYSQL для сортировки по связаной таблице учитывая только максимальные значения подмножества

Tags: mysql, sql, join, order

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
Product
-id
-name
```

---

```
Price
-id
-value
-product_id
-price_type
```

Т.е у продукта может быть несколько типов цены. 
Нужно задать сортировку по максимальной или минимальной цене (по связанной таблице Price столбца value) каждого продукта.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и делаете:

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, MAX(`p`.`value`) as `maxprice`, MAX(`p`.`value`) as `minprice` FROM `Product` `i`
INNER JOIN `Price` `p` ON `i`.`id` = `p`.`product_id`
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `maxprice`
```

В принципе, можно не выбирать даже эти значения а сразу написать `ORDER BY MAX(p.value)`.

Т.е., в любом случае конструкция ORDER BY отрабатывает после GROUP BY и HAVING. После неё только LIMIT идёт.